# Get poco property name

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I use ormlite with android and I've some poco class.

Example :

```
public class TableName {
  @DatabaseField(id = true)
  public Integer id;

  @DatabaseField
  public String prop;
}
```

I want to create sometimes

```
QueryBuilder<TableName, Integer> qb = dao.queryBuilder();
qb.where().eq("prop", "value");
```

I'd like to validate the "prop" string without using constants in my poco class (like PROPNAME). Do you know a efficiant way to do this ? (without heavy load stuff like reflexion).

I'd really like code validation.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ORMLite documentation organizes it this way, to avoid string literals everywhere:

```
public class TableName {
  public static final String FIELD_ID = "id";
  public static final String FIELD_PROP = "prop";

  @DatabaseField(id = true)
  public Integer id;

  @DatabaseField
  public String prop;
}

QueryBuilder<TableName, Integer> qb = dao.queryBuilder();
qb.where().eq(TableName.FIELD_PROP, "value");
```

Internally ORMLite uses reflection when you pass this string in, so it is unavoidable when using this library.

Comment: The documentation actually recommends that you then use the `@DatabaseField(columnName = FIELD_PROP)` on the field definitions.  Can you edit your answer to include that?